# Accepting Bitcoins on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, bitcoin

From what I've read, conventional wisdom is to generate a new Bitcoin address for each payment you're going to receive. However, since Heroku's file system is read only, where would you store the keys for each new address? [bitpiggy.herokuapp.com](http://bitpiggy.herokuapp.com) is running on Heroku and appears to accept Bitcoins. Does anyone have any idea how they accept and handle Bitcoins on the Heroku platform given that the file system is read only?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They appear to be using a 3rd party supplier, e.g. blockexplorer.com or blockchain.info, for Bitcoin services. See their "developer resources" page for the API they wrote to access those.

You could also create such a service yourself, just run it on EC2 or a rented server/VPS.